# Cakephp ajax form won't load the right view

Tags: cakephp, ajaxform, cakephp-2.4.7

I'm just trying to call a function from a form submision (which is also call from ajax).

I want to call the add method but it's the index which always called.

My ajax view with the ajax submission form :

```
<?php $count = count($files); ?>
<div id="message"></div>
<i><?= __('Nombre de fichiers liés : ') . $count ?></i>
<?= $this->Form->create('FilesManager', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'url' => array('action' => 'add'))); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<?= $this->Js->submit('Envoyer', array('update' => '#message', 'div' => false, 'type' => 'json', 'async' => false)); ?>
<?= $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

i've also tried :

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'url' => array('controller' => 'FilesManagers', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>

<?= $this->Form->create('FilesManager/add', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
```

EDIT

```
$this->Form->create('FilesManager', array('action' => 'add'))
```

Don't work for me but the form generated look like :

```
<form action="/agralis/files_managers/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FilesManagerIndexForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">...<input id="submit-838644811" type="submit" value="Envoyer"><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$("#submit-838644811").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({async:false, data:$("#submit-838644811").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#message").html(data);}, type:"post", url:"\/agralis\/FilesManagers"});
return false;});
//]]>
</script></form>
```

I can see that form action look good (when i copy/paste the action in the browser url he found the method) but the url called from the ajax submit button is wrong ! How can I change that ?

Comment: if the add action is in the same controller as the view calling it, try `$this->Form->create('FilesManager', array('action' => 'add'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The helpers are working independently

The `Js` helper is not aware of the `Form` helper, they don't interact with each other, and so the form URL is unknown to the `Js` helper.

The solution for *that* problem is rather simple, just look at the docs:

**[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::submit](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3asubmit)**

The `submit()` method accepts a `url` option where you can specify a URL in case the default one that is based on the current request doesn't fit you.

```
$this->Js->submit('Envoyer', array(
    'url' => array('action' => 'add')
    // ...
));
```

### File uploads are not supported

The next problem that you'll encounter is that the file upload doesn't work. That's not part of the question, but I'll broach the subject.

The `Js` helper doesn't support generating the required JavaScript to handle file uploads, it would need to make use of the `XMLHttpRequest` Level 2 (`xhr2`) functionalities that [**older browsers are lacking**](http://caniuse.com/xhr2).

You'll have to write custom JavaScript to handle that. Explanations and tutorials regarding that can be found all over the web.